# jQuery Navigation not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have the following code in a project for the main navigation.  It is essentially a css-sprite that is overlayed once the user hovers over the menu.  This is working perfectly in every browser except IE7 (ie6 not tested).  I have tried debugging my css and feel this is coming from jQuery / JS code specifically.  Is there some jQ code I may be using that is causing the error?  Any and all help is appreciated.

The issue is that once hovered the span is not showing in IE7.  All other browsers work a-okay.

```
  jQuery('#menu-main-navigation').find('li > a')
         .append('<span class="hover"></span>')
         .hover(function() {
              jQuery('.hover', this)
                .stop()
                .animate({
            opacity: 1
                }, 400 )
            }, function() {
           jQuery('.hover', this)
            .stop()
            .animate({
               opacity: 0
             }, 300)
             });                
          jQuery("#menu-main-navigation a").find('.hover').css({opacity:0})
```

Thank you in advance,

J

Comment: It helps when you tell us what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above is incorrect.  jQuery does support opacity for IE7.  It was a css issue after all, the positioning was off on the `<li>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 doesn't support `opacity`, you need `filter: alpha(opacity=50);`

It's not safe to code alone, take this http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is actually incorrect.  jQuery does support opacity for IE7.  It was a css issue after all the positioning was off on the li.  To the best of my knowledge jQuery does not implement features that cannot be supported cross browser.